# Is it possible to run apps that is created using C++ for WP8 on WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am going to develop WP8 application using C++ but i am wondering if it would be available for WP7 as well.

Comment: No, it won't. You can't write app for WP7 in C++.

Comment: I meant that can already created app for WP8 be runnable on WP7?

Comment: No, you can't. App for WP8 won't run on WP7.

Comment: Thank you for quickest response